# WMD Markdown from MySQL to HTML server site without showing the textarea

Tags: mysql, html, markdown, wmd

I store Markdown code in MySQL, and I’m worried about how to convert it back to HTML without transferring it through the WMD control and using massive data transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding -- the WMD control does Markdown to HTML conversion on the client web browser, in JavaScript.

But the Markdown text is no longer on the client -- it is on your server, in your MySQL database. Thus, you need a Markdown library that runs *on your server*.

Try checking the Markdown wiki page there are dozens of server Markdown libraries there.

http://xbeta.org/wiki/show/Markdown

Pick one, put it on your server, and run it on your server to convert the Markdown in your database to HTML.